# Bounding the spectral norm of the inverse of a matrix sum (useful bounds, tightest not necessarily needed)

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose $A$ is invertible and that $\|A\|_2,\|B\|_2,$ and $\|A^{-1}\|_2$ are known.

Are there any useful bounds (upper and/or lower) $||(A+B)^{-1}||_2$ in terms of the above quantities?

The bounds don't have to be the tightest possible, though of course tighter is always better. :)

Comment: Kato's [Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kato1.pdf#page=63) might be relevant.  (This link downloads the whole book.)

Comment: @KeithMcClary Do you suggest a particular lemma or chapter?

Comment: Chapter Two discusses how the eigenvalues change under perturbations.

Comment: @Lepidopterist Did you find the exact useful results? I'm dealing with this same problem now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Integral, one thing you can use is that if $A$ is positive definite $A^{-1}$ has a larger spectral norm than $(A+B)^{-1}$. I'm not sure off the top of my head but I think you can also have a lower bound as long as $A$ is positive definite, by looking at the eigenvalues of $(A+B)^{-1}$ and applying the Weyl eigenvalue inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

With the additional assumption that $I + BA^{-1}$ is invertible, one can obtain a very conservative upper bound via Woodbury identity, the triangle inequality, and Cauchy-Schwarz. Woodbury yields

$(A + B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}(I + BA^{-1})^{-1}BA^{-1}$,

then applying triangle and Cauchy-Schwarz you get:

$\|(A+B)^{-1}\| \leq \|A^{-1}\| + \|A^{-1}\|\|(I+BA^{-1})^{-1}\|\|B\|\|A^{-1}\|.$

This is a possibly a very conservative bound since it applies Cauchy-Schwarz several times and uses the triangle inequality to change a sign, and therefore may not be super useful.

The invertibility of $I + BA^{-1}$ is given if $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is positive semi-definite for example. And in that case you can bound $\|(I + BA^{-1})^{-1}\|$ by $\frac{1}{1+\frac{\lambda_\text{min}(B)}{\|A\|}}$, so $1$ in the case that $B$ is not full rank.